# Beginners guide in Writing own Custom Rules for Java in SonarQube

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm just a beginner towards static code analysis and I have adopted SonarQube for the purpose.
Right now I'm stuck at the point to begin customization. I need to know the **process or step by step guide to customize SonarQube i.e integrating my own rules for the language.**

I'm currently running
**SonarQube 4.2
Sonar-Scanner 2.5.1
Eclipse Mars M1 (Eclipse 4.5.0)
PostgreSQL 9.4**

Answer (score 2):

First, try using version 4.5.7 of SonarQube, as it is the current Long Term Support (LTS) version.

Then, have a look at the SonarQube documentation on [writing custom rules in Java](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Coding+Rules+using+Java). The [java-custom-rules](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/tree/master/java-custom-rules) maven project will then be a good starting point to write your own rules. It's an example project with some sampled rules.